# Working out dat.gui for first time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simply alert different messages based on what option is pressed in the dropdown list. I can't get it to work. How is it properly done?

```
var guiControls = new function() {
}
var gui = new dat.GUI();

this.message = 'dat.gui';
gui.add(this, 'message', ['pizza', 'chrome', 'hooray']).onChange(function() {
    if ( 'pizza') {
        alert("YUM!");
    } else if ('chrome') {
        alert("browser");
    } else if ('hooray') {
        alert("is ur bday?");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is missing from your code is the value:

```
gui.add(...).onChange(function(value) {
```

So your code should be like this:

```
var guiControls = new function() {
}
var gui = new dat.GUI();

this.message = 'dat.gui';
gui.add(this, 'message', ['pizza', 'chrome', 'hooray']).onChange(function(value) {
if (value=='pizza') {
    alert("YUM!");
} else if (value=='chrome') {
    alert("browser");
} else if (value=='hooray') {
    alert("is ur bday?");
}
});
```

It is shown well in this link: https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#7--Events

I hope I was helpful :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed what I wanted :)